# Please help integrate the function for system 2 given below and find flow equation

Tags: integration, solution-verification, dynamical-systems, absolute-value

Consider the system 1

$$ \dot x = f(x) = 1 − x^2$$

Consider this above equation on the domain $x > 1$ (something very similar should be true
for the case x < 1).

Find explicitly the solutions of the system 2 given below,

$$\dot y = \frac{f(y)}{(1 + |f(y)|)}$$

Where f is defined above. We need to show that for the second dynamical system given above

i) solutions exist for all times τ (maximal interval of existence is (−∞, ∞)),

and

ii) find the mapping of time and/or phase space which shows that these two equations are topological conjugate to each other.

=== [My Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJ1y2.jpg)

[image: one]

[image: two]

I noticed the typo above, I got an imaginary number when I put -1 limit in $\sqrt{y^2-2}$. I should have written  $\sqrt{y^2-2}$ in the final equation. But clearly, it seems wrong so I did not bother correcting it.

So I thought of breaking the second integral into 3 cases in order to handle the modulus function. But this assumes the initial condition is less than $-1$. I am pretty sure my answer is wrong since when I differentiate my solution I don't get back my question.

Please help me integrate this second system and find an explicit solution for the flow of the differential equation. After that, I can try to find a homeomorphism that shows these two systems are topologically conjugate.

Basically, help me do this integral -

$$\int \frac{|1-y^2|}{1-y^2} = \int \frac{|z|dz}{z \times -2y}$$

Answer (score 1):

okay, rearranging we get:
$$\frac{1+|f(y)|}{f(y)}\dot{y}=1$$
so we can express it as:
$$\int\frac{1+|f(y)|}{f(y)}dy=\int dt\tag{1}$$
now we also know that:
$$\frac{1+|f(y)|}{f(y)}=\frac{1+|1-y^2|}{1-y^2}=\frac{1}{1-y^2}+U_1(y)$$
where we will define:
$$U_1(y)=\begin{cases}1&-1<y<1\\-1&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

now the first part of the integral is easy but lets look at the second part:
$$\int_0^YU_1(y)dy\tag{2}$$
it is clear that if $-1\le Y\le1$ then we have:
$$\int_0^YU_1(y)dy=Y$$
Now just do the same for the other regions:
$$\int_0^YU_1(y)dy=\begin{cases}-(Y+2) & Y<-1\\Y & -1\le Y\le1\\-(Y-2)& Y>1\end{cases}$$
Hopefully this is what you were looking for

---

To visualise what this looks like, try doing the following in a graphing calculator:
$$f(y)=1-y^2$$
$$g(y)=\frac{1+|f(y)|}{f(y)}$$
Plot:
$$x=\int_0^yg(z)dz$$
this will give you a plot for $t$ vs $y$

Comment: ive noticed a mistake, editing now